# Is it possible to grant inbox delegation to a user, but filter what the users sees?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, exchange-2013

I have a CEO who has upwards of 100,000+ emails (80,000 unread). He recently hired an administrative assistant to help with his calendar. He now sees the value in having someone help with his inbox management.

However, he only wants her to see emails from outside our domain. No emails from internal users should be seen by his AA. We are on Exchange 2013.

I am fairly certain this isn't possible. But I thought I would ask to see anyone has encountered this issue.

Comment: Could you create a second email account for external mail, set up a rule to forward all mail to him from external sources to the new email account (and delete or archive it on his account), and then add the new email account both to his outlook and the AA's outlook?

Comment: That would defeat the purpose of having the AA clean up his inbox. Then we would have 2 mailboxes to deal with instead of 2.

Comment: Well, one of the mailboxes holds only the stuff that you've already said the AA shouldn't be cleaning up, so you still only have one mailbox that needs to be cleaned up, which both the AA and the CEO can see/organize. I'm not super familiar with exchange though - is two accounts with 50000 emails far worse than one account with 100000?

Comment: What's the specific version of outlook? Assuming that matters, but it sounds like a useful thing in the question

Comment: (Note, my proposed solution also assumes that you can mass export/import existing emails between accounts - I think that's possible, but I've not dealt with anything this scale before)

Comment: He's using Outlook 2011 (Mac Version), the AA is using Outlook 2013 Windows.

Answer (score 1):

With Exchange, addresses of internal senders contain:

- /O
- @mycompany.com

If not Exchange, addresses of internal senders contain:

- @mycompany.com

Set up a rule to move mail “with specific words in the sender’s address” to a folder where the permissions are changed so the administrative assistant does not have access.

Use “Run Rules Now” to move the backlog of internal mail.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe it's possible. You either have permission to view the mailbox or not.

There's no "mail item-level" permissions to apply.

Perhaps, instead, the CEO (or you) could setup an exception-based email rule on his mailbox that forwards/redirects the desired emails to the AA (without keeping a copy in his box), and then the AA can forward them back to the CEO as needed.

This should be pretty easily accomplished with Exchange/Outlook 2013.

Comment: Yeah we tinkered with the idea of forwarding email to the AA, but it defeats the purpose of wrangling the 100,000 emails he already has.